# Unable to build sencha app even having correct cmd and framework compatible versions

Tags: javascript, extjs, build, sencha-cmd

There is no debugger remained in all the code.All is fine on local.But as soon I started to build app it shows following error.
Moreover everything works fine in the development folder. However, when I try to create a production build, I get the following error.

```
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
    [ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExNotFound: Failed to find mixin class: mymixin.language
    [ERR]
    [ERR] Total time: 6 seconds
    [ERR] The following error occurred while executing this 
    line:C:\TestApp\apps\myapp_dev\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:367: The following error occurred while executing this line:C:\TestApp\apps\myapp_dev\.sencha\app\js-impl.xml:11: com.sencha.exceptions.ExNotFound: Failed to find mixin class: boseui.language9:35:39 PM"C:/Users/myaccount/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.4.84/sencha" app refresh
```

Comment: What command are you using to fire build ?

Comment: sencha app build production @Tejas1991

Comment: Any more details like ext version/sencha cmd version can help to understand

Answer (score 0):

In the development build there is no strict requirement enforcement, It'll be for production build.If that particular class is referenced anywhere in application or package consumed by the application then it is necessary to have that file and import it using "required" config, wherever there is usage.